# Passing struct array to function and calculating average in C?

Tags: c, arrays, function, struct

Beginner here, I've been trying this for hours and can't get it to work, searched online too and couldn't find an answer.

I'm trying to write a program where you input people by putting their age and height then calculate the average of each, and the average ratio of age to height. Whenever I pass the struct to my getAverage function, it returns the address (I think) instead of the averages.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct person
{
    int age;
    double height;
} Person;

double getAv (Person people[50], int max)
{

    int i;
    double total, retval;
    total = 0;
    for (i=0; i<=max; i++)
    {
        total = total + people[i].age;
    }

    retval = total / max;
    return retval;
}


int main (void)
{
    Person people[50];
    int i;

    while (i++, people[i].age>=0)
    {
        printf ("Person #%d\n", i);

        printf ("enter an age: ");
        scanf ("%d", &people[i].age);

        if (people[i].age<0)
            break;

        printf ("enter a height: ");
        scanf ("%lf", &people[i].height);

        printf ("\n");
    }

    double averageAge;
    averageAge = getAv (&people[50], i);
    printf ("%.1lf\n", averageAge);
}
```

Haven't implemented average height or ratio yet, just trying to get average of ages to work for now. When I try taking the & out of averageAge = getAv(&people[50], I); I get a compile error that tells me it needs the &. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `while (i++, people[i].age>=0)` you are using `i` uninitialized, same for `people[i].age`, you are accessing to some random element of an uninitialized array

Comment: You must also *check the return* of every user-input function. Otherwise you have no idea whether the input succeeded or failed. For instance when reading to type the `2` key to begin the age `20` the user slips and presses `'w'` by mistake -- a matching failure occurs, character extraction from `stdin` ceases and undefined behavior results when you then attempt to access the value. (lesson -- always validate every input by checking the return....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are serveral issues in you code, the first one:

```
Person people[50];
int i;

while (i++, people[i].age>=0)
```

You are using `i` uninitialized, thus, incrementing a variable containing garbage (or 0 as intended, but it is impossible to guarantee)

To avoid such problems in the future enable warnings on your compiler, the compiler would have told you something like:

```
‘i’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
```

So switch to

```
Person people[50] = {0};
int i = 0;
```

It seems (based on the pre-increment operator `++i`) that you want to use arrays with base 1, there is nothing wrong with that, but in your average function you are starting from `0`, so use a `for`:

```
for (i = 0; ; i++)
{
   ...
   if (people[i].age <= 0) break;
   ...
}
```

Another issue:

```
double averageAge;
averageAge = getAv (&people[50], i);
```

In this way you are passing only element 50 which is not part of your array (remember arrays are base 0 in C), to pass the entire array:

```
averageAge = getAv (people, i);
```

or

```
averageAge = getAv (&people[0], i);
```

The last one:

```
for (i=0; i<=max; i++)
```

You are including the element discarded when you was checking for `age > 0`, switch to:

```
for (i=0; i<max; i++)
```

A minor issue:

Iif the user enters 0 for the first element of `people` you end up dividing by 0

```
double averageAge;
averageAge = getAv (&people[50], i);
printf ("%.1lf\n", averageAge);
```

should be

```
if (i > 0)
{
    double averageAge;
    averageAge = getAv (people, i);
    printf ("%.1f\n", averageAge); // No need to use lf (long double)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do it this way, you need to receive in your function (Person& people[], int n)
Where n is the length of the array.
We use the '&' to not do copies of the array and also you are passing only the element with index 50 in the function, simply do only (people, n)

Comment: Question is tagged C, not C++

Answer (score 0):

there are mistakes in this code ,first you should initialize `int i` to `int i=0` in `mian` function.

how are using this condition `while (i++, people[i].age>=0)` when you haven't scanned any input it's like using an uninitialized variable. you need a `do-while` like this

```
    do 
    {
        printf("Person #%d\n", i);

        printf("enter an age: ");
        scanf("%d", &people[i].age);

        if (people[i].age < 0)
            break;

        printf("enter a height: ");
        scanf("%lf", &people[i].height);

        printf("\n");
        i++;
    } while (people[i-1].age >= 0);
```

also you are sending wrong arguments to your `getAv` function you should use `averageAge = getAv (people, i);`.

and in your function you have to remove `=` in this loop `for (i=0; i<=max; i++)` .this should be `for (i=0; i<max; i++)` ,otherwise the negative entered age will also be add to total and will affect the average.